# How to override CSS for a label that is part of a composite component?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, composite-component

I'm new to CSS and have a question that I don't seem to find any answer for it. I have a composite component, which is basically a Primefaces Checkbox, this is a composite component, for this element I would like to increase the width of the label.

I have tried to add styleClass="myStyle" to my checkBox and then in CSS:

```
.fullPanel.test label{
   width:25%;  
}
```

This is my checkBox:

```
<gcc:checkBox id="angabenKorrekt" label="#{messages['checkBoxLabel']}"
            value="#{bean.checkBox}" />
```

So looks my generated page, when inspecting it:
[HTML inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTrDo.png)

Basically I want to be able to change the default CSS for some of the UI elements. For now the style comes from: .fullPanel .inputBox label as shown in print screen.

Comment: in the image that you add about HTML inspector, the div with the class "fullPanel" do not have the class "test", so this CSS rules do not apply there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as per your html inspector, use `!important` only if there is no other way.

```
.fullPanel .inputBox label{
   width:25%;  
}
```

Comment: This way I will change the width for all my checkboxes, right? I would like to change only for selected ones.

Comment: this will change the all label which fall under .inputbox which have parent fullPanel - still if you want to make limited add one more class to fullPanel and use that as selector so will effect only specific.